# Multiple SELECTS and a CTE table

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have this statement which returns values for the dates that exist in the table, the cte then just fills in the half hourly intervals.

```
    with cte (reading_date) as (
    select date '2020-11-17' from dual
    union all
    select reading_date + interval '30' minute 
    from cte 
    where reading_date + interval '30' minute < date '2020-11-19'
)
select c.reading_date, d.reading_value
from cte c
left join dcm_reading d on d.reading_date = c.reading_date
order by c.reading_date
```

However, later on I needed to use A SELECT within a SELECT like this:

```
   SELECT serial_number,
register,
reading_date,
reading_value,,
ABS(A_plus)
FROM
(
SELECT
serial_number,
register,
TO_DATE(reading_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS reading_date,
reading_value,
LAG(reading_value,1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY reading_date) AS previous_read,
LAG(reading_value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY reading_date) - reading_value AS A_plus,
reading_id
FROM DCM_READING
WHERE device_id = 'KXTE4501'
AND device_type = 'E'
AND serial_number = 'A171804699'
AND reading_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('17-NOV-2019' || ' 000000', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24MISS') AND  TO_DATE('19-NOV-2019'   || ' 235959', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24MISS')
ORDER BY reading_date)
ORDER BY serial_number, reading_date;
```

For extra information:

I am selecting data from a table that exists, and using lag function to work out difference in reading_value from previous record. However, later on I needed to insert dummy data where there are missing half hour reads. The CTE table brings back a list of all half hour intervals between the two dates I am querying on.

ultimately I want to get a result that has all the reading_dates in half hour, the reading_value (if there is one) and then difference between the reading_values that do exist. For the half hourly reads that don't have data returned from table DCM_READING I want to just return NULL.

Is it possible to use a CTE table with multiple selects?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: It is unclear how you want to incorporate the two queries. Please provide sample data and desired results, and an explanation of the logic.

Comment: A CTE is just a kind of inline view that you can use more than once within the query. You can't save it separately for reuse in multiple queries. For that you would need to create a view or a [SQL Macro function](https://blog.sqlora.com/en/parameterized-views-in-oracle-no-problem-with-sql-macros/) (requires 19.8 or later).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you would like to achieve, but you can have multiple CTEs or even nest them:

```
with 

cte_1 as
(
    select username
    from dba_users
    where oracle_maintained = 'N'
),

cte_2 as
(
    select owner, round(sum(bytes)/1024/1024) as megabytes
    from dba_segments
    group by owner
),

cte_3 as
(
    select username, megabytes
    from cte_1
    join cte_2 on cte_1.username = cte_2.owner
)

select *
from cte_3
order by username;
```